# Read content between ""

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm scripting with VB.NET.

In a textbox1 I've the following content:

> I go "home"

Now I want to pick out all words which are between the quotation marks. In this example it is "home".

I can check if there are quotation marks in textbox1, but I can't pick out the text which is in it.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps _you_ get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [What makes a good question?](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: Use intellisense and look for methods that do useful stuff.

Comment: a regular expression would do it `".*"`

Comment: There are lots of ways you can think about doing this. A simple `String.IndexOf` (look it up on MSDN) would tell you where the `"`'s are and then you could use `String.Substring` to cut it out. Alternatively, you could use `Regex` (again, look it up on MSDN).

Comment: @Jodrell: I'd prefer `"(.*?)"`. The result will be in a capture group and it's non-greedy so you can capture multiple quoted words.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim s, result As String 
Dim index, index2 As Integer

s = TextBox1.Text
index = s.IndexOf("""") + 1

If index > 0 Then
    index2 = s.IndexOf("""", index)
    If index2 > 0 Then
        result = s.Substring(index, s.Length - index2)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

like this,

```
Regex.Match("I go ""home""", """.*""")
```

or, I prefer Matt Burland's suggestion, since it is non greedy.

```
Regex.Match("I go ""home""", """(.*?)""")
```

both of these will match `"home"` or anything else enclosed by double quotes.